# How I get monaco editor Action keybindings label

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, monaco-editor

I am usig monaco editor and my question is how can I get InternalEditorAction keybindings label text.
Like in the context menu:

[image]

Get actions in [monaco playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#interacting-with-the-editor-adding-an-action-to-an-editor-instance)

```
    var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: [
        '',
        'class Example {',
        '\tprivate m:number;',
        '',
        '\tpublic met(): string {',
        '\t\treturn "Hello world!";',
        '\t}',
        '}'
    ].join('\n'),
    language: "typescript"
});


editor.addAction({
    // An unique identifier of the contributed action.
    id: 'my-unique-id',

    // A label of the action that will be presented to the user.
    label: 'My Label!!!',

    // An optional array of keybindings for the action.
    keybindings: [
        monaco.KeyMod.CtrlCmd | monaco.KeyCode.F10,
    ],

    // A precondition for this action.
    precondition: null,

    // A rule to evaluate on top of the precondition in order to dispatch the keybindings.
    keybindingContext: null,

    contextMenuGroupId: 'navigation',

    contextMenuOrder: 1.5,

    // Method that will be executed when the action is triggered.
    // @param editor The editor instance is passed in as a convinience
    run: function (ed) {
        const actions = ed.getActions();
        console.log(actions[0])
 
        return null;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Monaco Editor default keybindings :

- editor._standaloneKeybindingService._cachedResolver._defaultKeybindings
- editor._standaloneKeybindingService._getResolver()._defaultKeybindings

Example:

```
const defaultKeybindings = editor._standaloneKeybindingService._getResolver()._defaultKeybindings;
const _id = 'editor.action.goToReferences';
const keyPart = defaultKeybindings.find(x => x.command === _id).keypressParts;

console.log(keyPart); // ['shift+F12']
```

ref: https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/287#issuecomment-521166743